# How in Python to upload a picture to the clipboard from url

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, http, clipboard

How in Python to upload a picture to the clipboard from url. Download it and upload to the clipboard in Windows 10.

Picture Example:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg/220px-Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg

[image: picture example]

Comment: First of all welcome. Please, add your own try of code within the question otherwise, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import win32clipboard

response = requests.get(url="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg/220px-Emergency_hospital_during_Influenza_epidemic%2C_Camp_Funston%2C_Kansas_-_NCP_1603.jpg")
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) # convert it to a "Image" Object
tempIO = BytesIO() 
image.save(tempIO,'BMP') # save it to a IO object as BMP format

# write it to clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB,tempIO.getvalue()[14:])
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```